# What's the exact behaviour of the command: ip address change?

Tags: networking, iproute

I have been fiddling with IPv6 and address lifetimes. I found out that the `valid_lft` attribute will make a v6-address disappear automagically, if used correctly. To extend an address' lifetime I would

```
ip addr change 1:2:3:4::1/112 dev eth0 valid_lft 86000
```

The use of `ip addr change` does not appear in any man-page I have access to (Debian,Ubuntu, and [online](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip)) and also not in the [official documentation](http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html). I found it in an [article](http://www.davidc.net/networking/ipv6-source-address-selection-linux) referring to an email from 2009 to the ipv6-ops mailing-list.

From what I could determine playing around, I guess one can always use `ip addr change` instead of `ip addr add`, because if an address does not exist, `ip` will add one, just if `ip addr add` was used.

Is that correct, i.e., can anybody explain what precisely `ip addr change` does and how it differs from `ip addr add`?

Comment: See also: [Server Fault: understanding "ip addr change" and "ip addr replace" commands](https://serverfault.com/q/476926/357116). The Microsoft Bing Chat AI directed me to that link. It seems very useful.

Answer (score 6):

When you are not sure of what something does, and the documentation doesn't say, you got to the sources, namely [line 1588](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git/tree/ip/ipaddress.c#n1588):

```c
if (matches(*argv, "change") == 0 ||
    strcmp(*argv, "chg") == 0)
    return ipaddr_modify(RTM_NEWADDR, NLM_F_REPLACE, argc-1, argv+1);
```

So, what it does? Returns the result of running the `ipaddr_modify()` function [defined in line 1379](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git/tree/ip/ipaddress.c#n1379) with the arguments `RTM_NEWADDR` and `NLM_F_REPLACE`.

> From what I could determine playing around, I guess one can always use `ip addr change` instead of `ip addr add`, because if an address does not exist, `ip` will add one, just if `ip addr add` was used.
>
> Is that correct, i.e., can anybody explain what precisely `ip addr change` does and how it differs from `ip addr add`?

No, `add` will create or execute the arguments given (if any is given), while `change` will look for the argument and replace it.

BTW, `replace` seems to be a compromise between `add` and `change` as it use a mixed bag of arguments.

Comment: And what is the effect of those flags? Because on the command line they don't really show. Especially as `change` works like `add` if the address to change does not exist yet. I didn't think I would have to dig through the kernel source (because that's where the flags are ultimately passed), in order to find out what one of the most popular command line tools for network management does. This isn't the 90s ... :-) But thanks anyways!

Comment: While this answer does point out that looking in the source code can help in case something isn't documented, it doesn't help me understand at all what the difference is between `ip address add`, `ip address change`, and `ip address replace`, nor when, how, and why I should use each.

Comment: See this answer instead: [Server Fault: understanding "ip addr change" and "ip addr replace" commands](https://serverfault.com/a/666521/357116). The Bing chat AI directed me to it, and it's very useful.